Concrete Mathematics: 2.26
I've been solving the exercise $\bf 2.26$ in Concrete Mathematics by Knuth, Graham and Patashnik:
Express $\prod\limits_{1\ \leq\ j\ \leq\ k\ \leq\ n}a_{j}a_{k} $ in terms of the single product $\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{n}a_{k}$

So to solve the problem, I squared the initial product using this property:
$$
\left[1 \leq j \leq k \leq n\right]^{2} =
\left[1 \leq j, \space k \leq n\right]\left[1 \leq j = k \leq n\right]
$$
where $\left[\cdots\right]$ is the Iverson Bracket.
And then I got the following:
$$
\prod_{\scriptstyle 1\ \leq\ j \atop \scriptstyle k\ \leq\ n}a_{j}a_{k}
\prod_{1\ \leq\ k\ \leq\ n}a^{2}_{k}
$$
And at this point I was almost stuck, but was quite surprised that the solution at the end of the book has the same formula, but then it does the following transformation of the first product ( which is the whole point of this question ):
$$
\prod_{\scriptstyle 1\ \leq\ j \atop 
\scriptstyle k\ \leq\ n} a_{j}a_{k} =
\left(\prod_{k = 1}^{n}a^{n}_{k}\right)^{2}
$$
which allows as to neatly express the initial product by taking square root ( and them some simple transformations ).
So, my question is: Is there a simple yet rigorous proof of this transformation ?.
It's kinda easy to see it by expansion, but that's not something I'm quite happy with :)


Are you sure about the $a_k^n$ factor?

It's basically the product rule of counting. The amount of squares in an $n$ by $m$ chessboard is $nm.$

@HackR , Sure. I double checked it with the book.

That $n$ does not belong in the exponent in your last equation.

Following Don Knuth's approach, we obtain in slightly more detailed steps
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\left(\prod_{1\leq j\leq k\leq n}a_ja_k\right)^2}
&=\left(\prod_{1\leq j,k\leq n}a_ja_k\right)\left(\prod_{1\leq j=k\leq n}a_ja_k\right)\\
&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^n\left(a_ka_j\right)\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^na_k^2\right)\\
&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\left(a_k^n\prod_{j=1}^na_j\right)\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^na_k\right)^2\\
&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^na_k^n\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^na_j\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^na_k\right)^2\\
&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^na_k^n\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^na_j\right)^n\left(\prod_{k=1}^na_k\right)^2\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(\prod_{k=1}^na_k\right)^{2n+2}}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.
Note: It is also instructive to compare the sum identity (2.33) from the book with this product identity as indicated by Don Knuth in problem 2.26. The following is valid
\begin{align*}
\sum_{1\leq j\leq k\leq n}a_ja_k=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^2+\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2\right)
\end{align*}
as well as
\begin{align*}
\prod_{1\leq j\leq k\leq n}a_ja_k
&=\left(\left(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k^n\right)^2\times \prod_{k=1}^n a_k^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^{n+1}
\end{align*}

Thanks a lot! That's a very detailed explanation, but could I ask you about the transformation which happens to the first factor after the third line? How could we "extract" the $a_k^n$ term out of the product?

@Jujumba: You're welcome. :-) Here we use $\prod_{k=1}^n(p_kq_k)=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n p_k\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^n q_k\right)$.

yeah that makes sense :) I just didn't realize that we have to preserve the second product, that's why my derivations have been unsuccessful. Thanks again!
